# Modify the behavior of NumericUpDown Control as NumericCyclic Control in winform application

Tags: c#, winforms, numericupdown

I am intended to achieve following behavior in the NumericUpDown Control used in the winform application.

When we click the down arrow key of the NumericUpDown control the value of the control decreases and in subsequent clicks its value continues to decreases until it reaches minimum value. After that the value remain unchanged for further clicking in down arrow key. The opposite behavior also true for clicking the up arrow key of the NumericUpDown control i.e. after reaching maximum value the value remain unchanged for further click in up arrow of the control.

I am trying achieve following behavior:

1. After reaching maximum value,if user clicks up arrow key the value set to minimum value of the control.
2. After reaching minimum value,if user clicks down arrow key the value set to maximum value of the control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a good behavior for `NumericUpDown` control, but if you want so,
you can Inherit from `NumericUpDown` and override `UpButton()`
and `DownButton()` like this

```
    public override void UpButton()
    {
        if (Value == Maximum)
            Value = Minimum;
        else
            base.UpButton();
    }

    public override void DownButton()
    {
        if (Value == Minimum)
            Value = Maximum;
        else
            base.DownButton();
    }
```

and use that inherited control instead of `NumericUpDown`.

Answer (score 2):

If you can spare the `Tag` you can do this:

```
private void numericUpDown1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    decimal old = numericUpDown1.Value;
    if (numericUpDown1.Tag != null) old = (decimal)numericUpDown1.Tag;

    if (old == numericUpDown1.Value && old == numericUpDown1.Maximum)
        numericUpDown1.Value = numericUpDown1.Minimum;
    else if (old == numericUpDown1.Value && old == numericUpDown1.Minimum)
        numericUpDown1.Value = numericUpDown1.Maximum;

    numericUpDown1.Tag = numericUpDown1.Value;
}
```

(Updated the buggy old answer)

Comment: this approach has an issue, when you set a value for the maximum and when your control is showing max-1 value and when you click the up arrow, it wont show max value, instead it will jump to the min value. same for the min value also..is there any solution for this ?

Comment: Whoops, good catch! See my update..!